# Ubuntu on LG 705

Tags: smartphone, lg

Can I install Ubuntu on LG P705 Optimus smart phone. I would like to install Ubuntu in my phone. Please advise if it is possible. Currently I have android 4.04

Comment: try this link but beware it flashes your phone completely - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-install-ubuntu-phone-tablet-preview-on-nexus-devices

Comment: Since when is the LG 705 a Nexus device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but this seems to be a entry level phone, on which Ubuntu currently cannot run (officially - experience may be very poor at best).

The semi-official minimum hardware requirements are that of the Galaxy Nexus, which are: Ti OMAP 4400, Qualcomm Snapdragon S4 (Nexus 4, may probably work with S3) or equal processor (LG 705 only has Qualcomm Snapdragon S1), 1GB of RAM and so on.

[Devices to which Ubuntu has been ported and where images are available](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) are listed in the Wiki, next to a [porting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting).